# Sending form variable data to another website on form submission

Tags: javascript

We have clients that we want to collect some of their form submission data for.  A user will fill out a form on their site and when the form is submitted, the following javascript is called:

```
    /* 4. Below script will get all field name/value pairs for given form */
function cpcshowElements(f) {
    var formElements = "";
    for (var n=0; n < f.elements.length; n++) {
        box = f.elements[n];
        if (!f.elements[n].value == ""){
            formElements += box.name + ":" + f.elements[n].value + ",\n";
        }
    }
    var track = new Image();

    /*send data to us*/
    track.src="https://www.xxx.com/form_record.cfm?form="+formElements;  
    //alert("The elements in the form '" + f.name + "' are:\n\n" + formElements);
}
```

This calls code on our end that should grab the data sent and save it.  This works great, but doesn't work all of the time.  When testing, we seem to not get the data consistently.  I haven't been able to figure out why this works sometimes and not others.  I'm not a javascript expert so I'm not sure if it's just the way javascript works.  The only thing I've been able to think might be the issue is that once the clients website finishes processing the form on their end and the user is directed to another page, the script will stop running if it hasn't already finished and so we won't get the data.  Anyone have any ideas?  Am I on the right track here?  Any ideas on how to make it so we will get the data every time?

Comment: Behavior is inconsistent when trying to do something when the page is being navigated away from. You could stop the form submitting behavior, set the `src` of that Image, and when the `load` event occurs (meaning the request to your server is done), submit the form.

Comment: I don't have any control over the clients website or their form behavior.  I got the client to add an onclick event to their form submission button that calls the above javascript file that they also included on their form page.  That's about the only thing they will allow.

Answer (score 0):

You could you [jQuery Framework with serialize function](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) tosubmit the form and get it input's values.

```
$("#bottonId").click(function(){


imageObj.src ="http://www.mypage.com/mypage?" +$("#form's ID").serialize();

});
```

Comment: I don't have any control over the form.  See my comment above.

Comment: I asked you if you know Jquery. If you dont, write the form  id and the submit buttom ID and i may help you.

Comment: I know jQuery enough to get by but not indepth at all.

Comment: Write what i told you them if you need help.

Comment: Most of our clients don't have IT people to do real actual programming for them.  Lots don't even have id's on their form fields or buttons.  But this is a good starting point for me to play around with.